# asp.net MVC giving a controller the name 'AdminController' makes it not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a ASP.NET application that uses ASP.NET MVC.
I tried naming one of my controllers "AdminController" meaning I typed "Admin" in the new controller text box and it filled out the controller part all by itself of course.
This controller never worked until I changed it's name. If I changed the name to anything else it worked with no problems.
I looked inside my Global.asax.cs file where the routes were configured and I found no routes leading to it.
I tryed adding a route to this new controller like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Admin", "calcul/SomeAction",
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "SomeAction" });
```

and it worked but then mysite\admin would only get routed to that specific action.

I renamed the controller to AdminSection and it works but I don't understand why it didn't work before.

Does anyone have any idea

Comment: Is there any sub folder under your app root with the name 'admin'?

Comment: Probably it's related to your context, there is no hardcoded default controller as Admin_Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @Cybernate I only made a subfolder with the name admin in my views folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was me, there was a area named admin that I didn't see. When I excluded it from the project the "adminController" controller started to work

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to create an explicit route for your controller if the default route matches it (controller/action/id).

Also, in the new controller text box you would need to type AdminController rather than just Admin.
The MVC framework will look for classes that end with this when looking for possible controllers.

Comment: I did type admin I said so in my post